# Firefox 9.0.1 Broke Internal Wiki Layout

Tags: firefox, mediawiki

The most recent version of Firefox has messed up our internal wiki layout so that the left bar menus are displayed below the content on all pages now.

I've tried using multiple resolutions and window sizes and the problem persists so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

There are no problems with Chrome or IE however.

A screenshot of the problem is attached here for you to see.[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using an old MediaWiki version.  It does UA sniffing and sends different code to different browsers, relying on bugs in some of the browsers to make the code sent to them render correctly.

Firefox 9 removed a nonstandard property that only Gecko used to implement.  MediaWiki was using that property to decide that the rendering engine was Gecko.  With it gone, MediaWiki now decides that you're using kthml and sends CSS rules tailored to khtml bugs... but Gecko happens to not have those bugs.  So the rendering ends up wrong.

Your options are to either update to MediaWiki 1.16 or newer (which you should do anyway, because your version is not getting security fixes anymore!) or wait for Firefox 10 to come out, because chances are that will restore the nonstandard property because too many sites were sniffing for it.

See also https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683151 and https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31807 for more info.

Comment: This may be the most complete answer I've ever received on any of the StackExchange sites...I appreciate your help!