# Old MediaWiki site broken in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, mediawiki

On Chrome I have a MediaWiki 1.13 installation that works on Firefox and IE 11, but the left menu appears below the content in Chrome.

How can I fix this without upgrading MediaWiki?

EDIT:

Found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808677/firefox-9-0-1-broke-internal-wiki-layout).

Also found [a compatibility page on Wikipedia](http://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Compatibility&oldid=996702) that implies that older versions of MediaWiki do not support Chrome.

Appears that the problem is server-side and I need to get the admins to upgrade to version 1.16 or above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My install was fixed by commenting out the contents of KHTMLFixes.css, as per https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28267

Comment: Brilliant, a fix with much less impact in a huge process-driven enterprise. Thank you.

Comment: More specifically, the file to edit for me was: `skins/monobook/KHTMLFixes.css`

Comment: @Ruskin, the impact in your enterprise will come from the technical debt accumulating in the non-upgraded wiki... A 1.13 wiki must be upgraded now.

Comment: @Nemo you're preaching to the converted there ... that contract has finished now and at a different client. They know it is an issue but red tape to get upgrade when system is slated for replacement is issue.

Comment: @Ruskin, sure. :) I was just adding the customary footnote for the casual reader.